# Send SMS messages to a Salesforce data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect, sms, audience

We are storing our audiences into a Salesforce DE, and we would like to use the same audiences for our SMS messages.
However, when we want to select an audience in MobileConnect, we don't have access to Salesforce Data extensions.

I would like to know if there is a possiblity to do that, or should we imperatively copy and import the audience to a Standard DE ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the data into a new DE.

When sending to a data extension Audience (directly from Mobile Connect without journeys) there's a hard requirement on the data extension configuration

- it needs to be sendable with the subscribe with the Subscriber Key included in the fields
- there needs to be one field of the "phone" type
- there needs to be one field of the "locale" type telling the system to  which country the phone number belongs to (there's probably some validation before a potential send)

Synchronized DE's would not be able to fill those requirements.